# Attaching debugger - android problem

Tags: android, debugging

I am new to android application development. Whenever I run a new app, after it gets installed and the activity launches, it displays a message saying "application is waiting for the debugger to attach" on the emulator. After that, application runs properly. But I am not getting what that message is and how  I can stop it from getting displayed. Could anyone help me...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its normal... when debugging it takes some time to connect to device or emulator. Its not a error message and u need not worry about it.

Some applications(I assume not yours) needs to have permissions to debug,  then u need to have this code

```
<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

In your manifest file .

or else have this

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

thanks

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Learnt something from both the posts.

Answer (score 1):

It means you run the application in debug mode to solve problems using the button shown on the screenshot.

Try the button at the right beside the debug button instead.

[image]